# Why Should We Use AsyncTask with a Return , Instead Running in UI Thread?

Tags: android, asynchronous

i have Trouble Understanding 1 Thing in Populating ListView, as My Experience says Methods Which run on UI Thread have most priority and so run alot faster than methods run in backGround but Difference is The UI Thread Will not Wait for Them to Finish so We Dont Feel any Lag in it.

But When We Using AsyncTask With a Result, Like This:

```
 Class async extends AsyncTasl<Void,Void,Bitmap>{

 @Override
 public Bitmap doInBackGround(Void...Params){
 .
 .
 .
  return new bitMap;
  }
}
```

since it returns some thing, so the MainThread MUST wait for it to finish, Which negates main purpose of running in backGround, So am i understanding Some thing Wrong, Or There is really no reason to do Such things in BackGround while they can run even Faster on UI Thread?

UPDATE :

my point is when we Use async.execute().get()

Comment: If the main thread would do `Result result = new AsyncTask().doInBackground()` (i.e. call the `doInBackground` method directly) it would have to wait on the result. But it does not. The result arrives magically in that `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: `async.execute().get()` **don't call that on the ui thread**. In does in fact negate the whole point of using an asynctask. What happens is that your bg thread does the work, while your ui thread sits waiting (blocked) for the bg thread to finish its job.

Comment: thats extacly what i meant, so why when i pass my imageView to the async task to set Bitmap After she is done, my row's positions get mixed up !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI thread behaves like any other thread that executes code, but as you pointed out, the main difference is that it's the thread that the user interacts with.

Picture this scenario:
You need to load list items that have an icon attached to them, and that icon lives at a URL and must be retrieved with a network request.

Here's some example code that fetches the image located at a URL whenever a list item appears on the screen:

```
public View getView(int position) {
    final URL imageURL = getURL(position);
    final Bitmap image = getImage(imageURL); //this will take a while
    ...
    view.setIcon(imageIcon);
    return view;
}
```

When working with list views on Android, that kind of call to getView happens whenever the user swipes through the list, as each list item appears on the screen.

If that's all done on the UI thread, the user is going to see a list that takes an agonizingly long time to load each list item. The main thread is not smart enough to cut long-running tasks short (what if that long running task happened to be saving important user data to an external DB somewhere?), so it has to let them finish entirely. It's also important to note that the UI Thread is not much different from any other thread from a system perspective. It's important because it's where the user experience happens.

That's why a best practice when writing any application on any platform is to offload long-running tasks to a background thread. The OS can handle switching between threads, which results in a UI that is extremely responsive to user actions (like swiping through a list).

As ABFORCE demonstrated, you should fetch images with an AsyncTask on Android. In the background, a request will be made to the URL's for the image, and only when the final image is ready to be shown on the page will a call be made to the UI thread to display it. The user would see a list that they can swipe through quickly, and images would pop into each list item as they are fetched. We don't want to hold the user up from *doing something*, so we want to make sure they can swipe through the list as fast as they want.

UPDATE:
If you were to do new AsyncTask().execute.get(), that method would indeed block on the UI thread, negating the benefits of a background thread. What you may need to do in your class that extends AsyncTask is hold a reference to the View you want your image a part of (I'm assuming a new AsyncTask per list item), and in onPostExecute, set whatever field that needs to be set on that view.

Example:

```
class async extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap>{

    private View view;

    @Override
    public Bitmap doInBackGround(Void...Params) {
        /* Here is background thread */
        return new Bitmap(); ----+
    }                            |
                                 | //this object will be passed here
    @Override                    V
    public void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        /* Here is main thread */
        view.setIcon(result);
    }
}
```

elsewhere...

```
public View getView(int position) {
    new async(view).execute();

    return view; //View will return now, and the image will populate later
}
```

There are obviously many ways to do this, and that's one off the top of my head.

Comment: im trying to do that all the time, but my Row's in the List get mixed up and their positions will be wrong when i pass my ImageView reference to the async task, so he sets Bitmap into it onPostExecute, so i had no choice but using get() method of async task !

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks are a good way to perform operations in the background without blocking the main UI thread.

When you call asyncTask.execute(),

- onPreExecute(..) callback is issued on the UI thread
- doInBackground(..) is called on a background thread (If I understand your question correctly, the main thread is not waiting here). When you get the data from a server (say) in this method, you return the data so that the Android system will call onPostExecute with this data on the UI thread
- onPostExecute(..) is issued on the UI thread with the data you returned in doInBackground(..) as a parameter.

Comment: it is not always slike this, when you execute it with async.execute().get , thats how you fill a listView without row's getting mixed

Comment: Yes, you need to set the tag on the view so that the mix up does not take place.

Comment: if you mean ViewHolder, but still :(

Answer (score 0):

No, main thread does not wait for the task to be complete, That return value will be passed to `onPostExecute(...)` method. This method will be run on main thread and takes that return value as its own input argument.

```
Class async extends AsyncTasl<Void,Void,Bitmap>{

    @Override
    public Bitmap doInBackGround(Void...Params){
        /* Here is background thread */
        return new Bitmap(); ----+
    }                            |
                                 | //this object will be passed here
    @Override                    V
    public void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
        /* Here is main thread */
    }
}
```

Comment: like i mentioned above, i meant when you call async.execute().get , otherwise the ListView items will get mixed, atleast in my case it does when i pass imageView to the async to set drawable